# Nginx error in my aws elastic beanstalk log files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have deployed my nodejs rest API on elastic beanstalk configured with an nginx server and i am getting the following error:

```
2021/03/03 15:01:15 [error] 18614#0: *1381 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.17.180, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.43.117"

2021/03/03 15:01:30 [error] 18614#0: *1385 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.17.180, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.43.117"

2021/03/03 15:01:45 [error] 18614#0: *1389 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.17.180, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.43.117"
```

I have tried alot of things and also added an .ebextensions folder in my root directory with a file named nginx.config having the the following configuration which is provided by aws documentation but it still doesnt seem to work. I have spent 3 days trying to resolve this problem but i am unable. I will appreciate if someone can help me figure this out

**My nginx configurations is as follows :**

```
files:
/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
mode: "000644"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    keepalive 256;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location /static {
        alias /var/app/current/static;
    }

  }

/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/99_kill_default_nginx.sh:
mode: "000755"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  #!/bin/bash -xe
  rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
  service nginx stop 
  service nginx start

container_commands:
removeconfig:
command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf 
/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `nginx` setting you are trying to use (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`) is for **Amazon Linux 1**.

Since you are probably using **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2) you should be using different files for setting nginx. For AL2, the `nginx` settings should be in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not in `.ebextentions` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). Or if you want to fully overwrite the main `nginx.conf` you should provide its custom version using `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Assuming your nginx config is fine, you can try creating file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf` with content of:

```
  upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    keepalive 256;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location /static {
        alias /var/app/current/static;
    }

  }
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I will be glad if you could let me know how to do that. From what i understand you are telling me to delete the ebextesions folder and create a folder name ".platfrom" in the root containing an nginx folder with a file conf.d. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @FaheelMohammad Yes. In AL2 nginx is set using .platform, not .ebextesions. I can't advice of actual content of the files there as your nginx configuration maybe incorrect in itself.

Comment: Okay ill try to copy the above config in the path you defined and will mark you question as accepted if everything works out. Thanks

Comment: @FaheelMohammad I updated the answer with what you can try.

Comment: Yes. I am looking into itt

Comment: I have tried and created the file as you siggested the error isnt resolved and showing the same thing again

Comment: @FaheelMohammad Can you ssh to the eb instance, modify nginx manually to fix the issue, and the replicate in eb config files?

Comment: I can ssh in the instance and do as you said but i didnt get what you meant by " and the replicate in eb config files"

Comment: @FaheelMohammad What changes you made manually, must be reflected in your eb config files for automated deployment.

Comment: my defaut nginx config lies in /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf. Do you want me to modify this file with the config you provided right?

Comment: where can i find eb config files ?

Comment: @Marcin - this led to make the elastic beanstalk health severe. Didn't fix the issue. The error told me to look at the /var/log/eb-activity.log and I didn't see any issue highlighted